# Issue with Graphics after removing the upstart from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upstart

I was installing git on Ubuntu.

When I installing git, I got below error in there. (I got the similar kind error when I do the uprade also.)

```
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

Then I tried to fix this as mentioned on [this](https://github.com/huginn/huginn/issues/1949) post by JamiePhonic.

There I did the below steps and I got the git issue fixed.

**Step 1:** `sudo dpkg -l | grep upstart`
    This returns the installed information.

**Step 2 :** `sudo apt-get remove --purge upstart`
    This returns the installed information. So, I didn't installed the fgetty using below commanf. sudo apt-get install fgetty

**Step 3 :** `sudo apt-get remove --purge upstart`
    Since Step 1 returns the installation information (t means that upstart or some part of it is installed in some form), I tried to remove it using this command

**Step 4 :** I removed runit using the below command
    sudo apt-get remove --purge runit

**Step 5 :** Then I run a clean as mentioned below
    sudo apt-get clean

After this, I re-installed the git and everything went fine.

But after I restart the NoteBook, I got below error while it is booting up.[image]

When I check the log further, I noted that there are some errors loading some UI artifacts (eg :fonts etc).
[image]

Can anyone give an idea on fixing this without reistalling Ubuntu.

- OS : Ubuntu : 16.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was able to solve this re-installing ubuntu desktop as mentioned in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) post.

It says :

> "When the message that "your system is running in low-graphics mode"
>   appears, press Ctrl+Alt+F1, then login with your credentials.
>
> And then, run the following commands:
>
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop sudo reboot"